# java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to /192.168.10.110 connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused

Tags: java, android, sockets, ip, client

**First problem:**
I am doing messaging using socket programming.Previously it worked fine but currently it is showing exception when I connect both server and client to same router .

**Second problem:**
If I connect server and client to different networks it is not working client unable to connect server's ip address

Comment: `192.168.x.x` is an internal IP address. You cannot expect it to work across different networks. For that, you'll need a host accessible from both networks to run the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

192.168.0.0/16 is a Local Area Network address block.

Moreover, if your server machine is configured to use DHCP instead of a static address, it may receive a different local address each time you connect it to the (same) router.

Comment: previously it worked for me currently it is showing exception and sometimes showing no route to dns what changes i have to do make to work properly

Comment: @user1900264, but the ip can change on reboot.

Comment: it is assigning same ip address to both server and client everytime when i reboot both mobile and router